# Getting Groups which are Communities in Liferay

Tags: liferay

I am trying to get all the groups which are communities in Liferay 5.2.x version.
Currently I am doing the following.

1) `List<Group> groups = GroupLocalServiceUtil.getGroups(0, groupCount)` --> Get all the existing groups

2) Iterate over the groups list to check if the group is a community by using `group.isCommunity()`.

Please suggest a way to get all the groups which are communities at one shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use:

```java
GroupLocalServiceUtil.search(
         long companyId, String name, String description,
         LinkedHashMap<String, Object> params, int start, int end)
```

With name, description having a blank string passed. Params being null or an empty LinkedHashMap. Start and end being what every you desire (passing -1 to both will get the entire set).

Your final call would look something like:

```java
GroupLocalServiceUtil.search(companyId, "", "", null, -1, -1)
```

Comment: Hi RP,  Thanks for your response, unfortunately this method is not in 5.2.x, Sorry I forgot to mention the version in my post.

Comment: No problem, let me look for the 5.2.x version.

Comment: Ok, I've found that using the search method from GroupLocalServiceUtil in 5.2.x will ALWAYS return Groups of type Commmunity. See my edited answer

Comment: Hi RP, I have a question related to this here .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275509/getting-groups-which-are-communities-in-liferay

Comment: Hey Michael, I think you've linked this very same page.